# Inserting an If Condition in the middle of an existing Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

in the latest ADF UI, there doesn't appear to be a way to add an IF Condition Block and reference another Block in the pipeline upon Success.  The Old UI worked seamlessly, but the new one just allows you to add a new block - but not one from the existing Pipeline.

Comment: Hi @RobertM, if my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @RobertM, do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

We could add the new IF Condition block to the exist pipeline and reference it to other Block easily.

As we know in the Data factory, the default green arrow means Success:
[image]

When we add the If Condition block and reference to other block, we could click the green arrow and it will be bold. We can enter 'Delete' key to delete it：

[image]

Now we can reference the block to other block, please see bellow gif:
[image]

I think the new Data Factory UI also is simple and easy to use.

Comment: Hi the issue is that you do not have a True condition (in the If Condition block) - as it says no activities under True.  If you click on the edit beside True, it brings up an empty palette and you cannot get the the next item in the flow (Copy data 1).  By connecting the If Condition, the way you did, it will always flow true as there if no activity defined for either True or False .  Note: I can get this to work by defining multiple pipelines and putting the first half in the pipeline and setting the True condition to the second Pipeline.

Comment: @RobertM yeah, can you please edit your question? Maybe you could give some UI screenshoots, so that we can understand you clearly.

Comment: For the new UI, we must put the active(Copy data1) under to the true active. then in if condition true active, we could build a new work flow.